# Django start-up code (like initial caching) conflicts makemigrations. Operational Errors no such columns tables

Tags: python, django

First of all I'm not a fan of "do it the django way" thing. Instead of spending hours to learn the django way I prefer to utilize my basic programming knowledge when I develop an application. 
Background :

- Application I'm developing is a REST backend that stores localization values like language information.
- I want to take language information that is stored in the database and load it into memory once at startup and then serve that data from memory when a request comes.
- I created my model

```
    class Text(models.Model):
        language = models.CharField()
        key = models.CharField()
        text = models.CharField()
```

- Then ran python manage.py makemigrations and migrate commands as a regular step
- Then I jumped ahead and implemented my caching code and put it directly under admin.py(it could be urls.py it does not matter, it only needs to be run once)

```
    cached_languages = models.Text.objects.all()
```

- I go ahead and run my app and it is just working fine.
- Then I wanted to add a field to my Text model like

```
    class Text(models.Model):
        language = models.CharField()
        key = models.CharField()
        text = models.CharField()
        **dummy = models.CharField()**
```

- Then hit python manage.py makemigrations command and **boom** at line

```
cached_languages = models.Text.objects.all()
```

We get an error saying that 
*sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: app_text.dummy*

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that django executes every line of code that is written even when you call *python manage.py makemigrations*. This means before django actually reflects the alterations to database it executes entire project and when it comes to the caching line it tries to get all rows from Text table which does not yet have column *dummy* but from django perspective (in code) table Text has a column dummy that's why it throws an error.

**Solution** A workaround is to put a flag in say settings.py

```
IS_RUNNING = False
```

and in manage.py add the following

```
from app import settings
if 'runserver' in sys.argv:
    settings.IS_RUNNING = True
```

and put your cache code after a flag check

```
if settings.IS_RUNNING:
     cached_languages = models.Text.objects.all()
```

then django won't try to get records while making migrations before applying them. The cache algorithm will only execute when you actually call runserver.

Comment: Hope this helps someone that is struggling with basic caching

Comment: It's a bad idea to ever execute a query on start-up, there are still several issues with this solution. When a new `Text` object is created your cache is out of date. What happens when you add a field to the model and run `makemigrations`?

Comment: 1)Why is it a bad idea to execute a query on startup?
2)You can update your cache by starting a daemon thread, and it can update your cache every say 300 seconds you can read this value from settings.py or another config file. I never mentioned an update of a cache though. That was not the point.
3)I don't really get your third sentence. You first stop the server and run your migrations then start and you have your cache refreshed.